# Safari Private Window vs Normal Window Massive Performance Difference

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, xmlhttprequest

I was debugging OpenSpeedTest for 10Gbps and saw massive Performance difference in Private window vs Normal window.

[image]

I don't know why is this happening. Where to start or how to solve this.

Here is the Youtube Video of Full Test https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMKnSdsdwEg

This is Application make a bunch of XHR requests to run this benchmark. In normal window it looks like some additional security check or processing happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of extensions like adblock or unlock.

Comment: No Extensions installed. Fresh M1 Mac.